# first() returns and array instead of stdClass object - Laravel 5.3 MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.3

I have setup two fresh Laravel 5.3 with different databases. One with MongoDB(using https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb) and another with MySQL.

I have run this simple code on both setup:

```
$user = DB::table('users')->first();
dd($user);
```

For above code, Laravel with MySQL returns **stdClass object** whereas Laravel with MongoDB returns **an array**  .

Why is that? Is there any way that I can make it same as Laravel MySQL i.e **stdClass object**?

Due to this different return type issue, I'm not able to use another package with Laravel MongoDB setup.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Parth vora

Answer (score 0):

Just add "$user = (object)$user;" in "vendor/jrean/laravel-user-verification/src/UserVerification.php"

```
/**
 * Get the user by e-mail.
 *
 * @param  string  $email
 * @param  string  $table
 * @return stdClass
 *
 * @throws \Jrean\UserVerification\Exceptions\UserNotFoundException
 */
protected function getUserByEmail($email, $table)
{
    $user = DB::table($table)
        ->where('email', $email)
        ->first();

    if ($user === null) {
        throw new UserNotFoundException();
    }
    $user = (object)$user;
    $user->table = $table;

    return $user;
}
```